# viewport can't satisfy mobile screen?

Tags: html, css, viewport, mobile-website

I'm web developer.
I developed my mobile website use 'viewport' option in html for responsive mobile website.

Then, I assigned meta data like this below:-

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=320"/>
```

But my web site occurs right margin(below pic is part of my web site menubar)

How can delete right margin? .... Thanks for your help!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EiZBq.jpg)
....

Comment: use <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0"/>
And media queries to make site responsive.

Comment: @Roy use backticks `  `<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0"/>` . makes things in comments easier to read. `:-)`

Comment: wow , great! thanks a lot Roy and Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write this and try if it works...

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can need to change your media query to this and this would difinilty work for your in website. Please vode if i m correct.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
```

EDIT: 
By giving static width, you are already loosing the responsiveness. Instead use `device-width` which would automatically take the device's width.

`max-scale=1.0` and `user-scalable=no` wouldn't allow the user to pinch zoom on the mobile. If you want to let the user zoom in on the website, you can remove these two

Comment: why does this get -1? This is correct, but can be much improved by explaining *why* this works.